# Sharing Text, i.e. the missing <CR>

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am using "Sharing" to send text (string) by email.

the data I am sharing is created like this:

```
string data = "Log Data\n" + "========\n";

data += "Log Type   : " + log.LogType.ToString() + "\n";

data += "Date/Time:   " + log.TimeStamp.ToString( "MM/dd/yy - HH:mm:ss" ) + "\n";

data += "Result:      " + log.Result.ToString() + "\n";

data += "Value1:      " + log.Value1 + "     Value2:      " + log.Value2 + "\n";

data += "Note:        " + log.Note + "\n\n";
```

the data is prepared and sent in an email. However the "\n" is not interpreted correctly neither before I send (by the Windows 8 mail program) or the receiving side GMail.

The data presented on the send side looks like this:

```
Log Data ======== Log Type : ToDo Date/Time: 06/05/12 - 08:00:00 Result: Normal Value1: 170 Value2: 0 Note: note 1
```

The ShareTextHandler is like this:

DataRequest request = e.Request;

```
request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share Data: ";

request.Data.Properties.Description = "Send Data to an email address";

request.Data.SetText( data );
```

Was the "\n" changed in Windows 8? or the SetText does something to remove it?

EitanB

UPdate....

Hi,

Tried to do it with HTML:

Tried some test data with HTML like this:
        private string PrepareShareData()
            {
            string CR = System.Environment.NewLine;
            string data = string.Empty;

```
        data += "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Final//EN\">" + CR;
        data += "<html>" + CR;
        data += "<body>" + CR;
        data += "<p>" + CR;
        data += "Log Data" + "<br/>" + CR;
        data += "========" + "<br/>" + CR;
        data += "Line 1" + "<br/>" + CR;
        data += "Line 2" + "<br/>" + CR;
        data += "<p>" + CR;
        data += "</body>" + CR;
        data += "</html>" + CR;

        return data;
        }
```

Did not work...

Tried also:

```
    private string PrepareShareData()
        {
        string CR = System.Environment.NewLine;
        string data = string.Empty;

        data += "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Final//EN\">";
        data += "<html>";
        data += "<body>";
        data += "<p>";
        data += "Log Data" + "<br/>";
        data += "========" + "<br/>";
        data += "Line 1" + "<br/>";
        data += "Line 2" + "<br/>";
        data += "<p>";
        data += "</body>";
        data += "</html>";

        return data;
        }
```

did not work either....

I did create a .HTML file with the notepad that worked fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Final//EN">
<html>
<body>
<p>
Log Data<br/>
========<br/>
Line 1<br/>
Line 2<br/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a mail problem with HTML too or my HTML is wrong?

Thanks,
EitanB

Comment: Try using string CR = System.Environment.NewLine; instead of "\n". Let me know if this helps

Comment: Tried it. CR is adding <CRLF> \n\r but the mail program removes both, so this is not a workaround.
Thanks for you input,
EitanB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used:

```
var htmlFormat = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat( data );
request.Data.SetHtmlFormat( htmlFormat );
```

Where data is:

```
        string data = string.Empty;
        string BR = @"<br/>";
        data += @"<html>";
        data += @"<head><title>";
        data += @"<title>";
        data += @"Log Data<br/>";
        data += @"========<br/>";
        data += @"</title>";
        data += @"</head>";
        data += @"<body>";
        data += @"Date/Time:   " + log.TimeStamp.ToString( "MM/dd/yy - HH:mm:ss" ) + BR;
        data += @"Note:        " + log.Note + BR + BR;
        data += @"</body>";
        data += @"</html>";
```

too much work to go around Microsoft problem....

EitanB

Answer (score 1):

try args.Request.Data.SetHtmlFormat(HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(html));

Answer (score 0):

Environment.Newline is certainly a step in the right direction, but I don't know if it will solve your problems.

This was an issue in the inbuilt mail app in Consumer Preview (and I haven't checked if it was fixed in RTM).  I noticed that it didn't seem to want to respect line breaks.  I confirmed that the correct data was being sent by writing a small dummy share target and ensuring that the text was rendered correctly and it was.  Maybe you could send HTML in the share request - mail supports HTML as well as Text.

Comment: Hi,
Please see my edit in my question. I tried it with HTML with no success either.
Thanks
EitanB

Answer (score 0):

First of all as a general rule of thumb we should always be using a StringBuilder object to be appending strings together. The reason for this is: the string variable is immutable so every time we add a "+" sign we actually end up creating an entirely new instance of the string variable.

```
string data = string.Empty;
data += "Some Text Creates 1 variable";
data += "This creates a second variable" + "and this a third";
return data;
```

is better suited as

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()

builder.Append("Some Text Creates 1 variable");
builder.Append("Since we havent yet created a string no 2nd variable is created");
builder.AppendLine("Should create a return before this line");
builder.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
builder.AppendLine("Should have an empty line above it");
return builder.ToString();
// only creates 1 string variable
```

Or you could wrap the single variable in the HTML Encode method described

```
return System.Net.WebUtillity.UrlEncode(builder.ToString());
```